# Adding to a variable with a function JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've only started learning Javascript for a few hours, and am trying to use a function to add to a variable using JS within HTML (Sorry if I used the wrong terminology) and it doesn't seem to be changing the result.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            var userID = 1;
            var userRep = 0;
            function NumUp(userRep) {
                userRep = userRep + 1;
            }
            function NumDown(userRep) {
                userRep = userRep - 1;
            }
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="Reputation.JS">
            <div class="container">
                <p>result goes here</p>
                <button type="button" onclick="NumUp()" id="voteUp">Vote Up</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="NumDown()" id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
                <label id="lbl"></label>
                <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
                <p id="demo"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Much thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: As per your code, Numbup and Numdown requires arguments but you are not passing that at the time of call

Comment: Sorted much thanks guys

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will help. Thank you.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        var userID = 1; 
        var userRep = 0;
        function NumUp(){
            userRep = userRep + 1;
            myFunction();
        }
        function NumDown(){
            userRep = userRep - 1;
            myFunction();
        }

        function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="Reputation.JS">
        <div class="container">
            <p>result goes here</p>
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumUp()"  id="voteUp">Vote Up</button> 
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumDown()"  id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
            <label id="lbl"></label>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to pass the arguments to the method you are calling since that argument is already a global variable.

```
function NumUp() {
  userRep = userRep + 1;
}

function NumDown() {
  userRep = userRep - 1;
}
```

When you define a function that accepts an argument `userRep`, but don't pass the value when you invoke that function, it will go as `undefined` and adding a number to it will result in `NaN`. **Also that value is localized since you used the argument value for computation instead of the global value** - which is why value doesn't change.

**Demo**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO supply a title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script>
    var userID = 1;
    var userRep = 0;

    function NumUp() {
      userRep = userRep + 1;
    }

    function NumDown() {
      userRep = userRep - 1;
    }

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
      <p>result goes here</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="NumUp()" id="voteUp">Vote Up</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="NumDown()" id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
      <label id="lbl"></label>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

remove userRep from NumUp and Numdown which is a localvariable inside the function and its value becomes undefined when you dont provide.

```
function NumUp(){
         userRep = userRep + 1;
    }
function NumDown(){
         userRep = userRep - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code

```
function NumUp(userRep){
     userRep = userRep + 1;
}
```

This `userRep` is a local variable and you are trying to print the value for global variable. so that it is displaying always `0` because global didn't changed.

Also if you didn't mentioned any `type` in `button` element, that will treat as `submit` button. If you don't want to submit the form then just add `type=button`.

Solution is to remove the argument or change the name of that argument in your function.

```js
var userID = 1; 
        var userRep = 0;
        function NumUp(){
            userRep = userRep + 1;
        }
        function NumDown(){
            userRep = userRep - 1;
        }

        function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
        }
```

```html
<form action="Reputation.JS">
        <div class="container">
            <p>result goes here</p>
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumUp()"  id="voteUp">Vote Up</button> 
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumDown()"  id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
            <label id="lbl"></label>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
        var userID = 1;
        var userRep = 0;
        function NumUp () {
            userRep = userRep + 1;
        }
        function NumDown () {
            userRep = userRep - 1;
        }

        function myFunction (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="Reputation.JS">
        <div class="container">
            <p>result goes here</p>
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumUp()"  id="voteUp">Vote Up</button>
            <button type ="button" onclick="NumDown()"  id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
            <label id="lbl"></label>
            <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you, remove userRep from NumUp and Numdown which is a local variable inside the function

```html
<html>
            <head>
             <title>TODO supply a title</title>
               <meta charset="UTF-8">
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
               <script type="text/javascript">
                  var userID = 1;
                  var userRep = 0;
                  function NumUp() {
                     userRep = userRep + 1;
                  }
                  function NumDown() {
                     userRep = userRep - 1;
                  }
                  function myFunction() {
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userRep;
                  }
               </script>
            </head>
            <body>
             <div class="container">
                    <p>result goes here</p>
                    <button type="button" onclick="NumUp()" id="voteUp">Vote Up</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="NumDown()" id="voteDown">Vote Down</button>
                    <label id="lbl"></label>
                    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
                    <p id="demo"></p>
                </div>
            </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks very much worked brilliantly, as for as I can see my only problem was I had included the type button attribuite, is this right, and if so why is this?

Comment: Hi mate, No need to pass the arguments to the method you are calling since that argument is already a global variable if you didn't mention any type of button element, that will treat as submit button. If you don't want to submit the form then just add type=button, rest all code is perfect